# Why are most helipads in São Paulo blue coated and identified by a "P"?

Tags: airport-design, icao-sarps, helipad

ICAO Annex 14, Vol II and FAA (AC 5390-2C) standards establishes 'H' and there is no mention to coating TLOF or FATO.
Brazilian National Regulation (RBAC 155 - ANAC) does not provide any guideline for the blue painting.
I would like to know where this common São Paulo helipad pattern comes from.

[image]

Examples:

- [Google Maps (1)](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-23.5721394,-46.6983116,66m/data=!3m1!1e3)
- [Google Maps (2)](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Manuten%C3%A7%C3%A3o+Aeron%C3%A1utica/@-23.5645705,-46.8308878,222m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x94cf001950dc6975:0x1ad59b1516cd128c!8m2!3d-23.5641725!4d-46.8308301)
- [Google Images](https://images.app.goo.gl/JSFTRsNF424CYaQZ7)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the [Rules for Heliports in Sao Paulo](http://www.abtengenharia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/IT-31-HELIPONTO-E-HELIPORTO.pdf), the P means that it is private heliport. H for public Heliports,  M is for military. Hospitals use the letter H on a red cross, also when they are private or military hospitals. Examples are given in the pictures below.

It seems that the color blue is not required by the regulations; there are various other colors used in Sao Paulo (see a few examples below I found on Google maps).

I think blue is used mostly because it provide good visual contrast with the white or yellow markings. White paint on concrete can be difficult to see under bright sunlight conditions. The blue color also stands out from the urban environment, making the helipads easy to spot from the air. Try it on [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@-23.5911238,-46.681158,876m/data=!3m1!1e3); the blue helipads are relatively easy to find on the satellite view.

This video explains the markings (in Portuguese)

---

[image: Hospital helipad with H marking and red cross]

Hospital helipad with H marking and red cross

---

[image: Military helipad with M marking]

Military helipad with M marking

---

[image: Green helipad with circular border and 05 Marking]

Green helipad with circular border and 05 Marking

---

[image: Concrete helipad with circular border and 05 Marking]

Concrete helipad with circular border and 05 Marking

---

[image: Red private helipad]

Red private helipad

---

[image: Green private helipad]

Green private helipad

All images are screenshots from Google maps

Comment: In federal level, ANAC (RBAC 155/2018) sets only "H" as identification letter. However, such regulation is obligatory only for private facilities modified after 2018 (if elevated). Hence, the use of "P" might be transitionary.

Comment: Do you know what the numbers and arrows mean?

Comment: @expeditedescent The triangle is pointing to the magnetic north, the number indicates the maximum allowable weight of the helicopter in metric tonnes and the small arrow(s) are used to indicate the approach path.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen only one helipad so marked, and it was reserved for police operations.

Comment: NB My observation was in the continental US, and the pad was marked with a round circle, with a P.  I asked the FBO lineman, and he said it was reserved for police helicopters.  As I recall, it was in the late 1980's and I will try to recall the airport.